# How to assign a click event for dynamically created div using multiple instance in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have written code for creating dynamic div which looks like a small window using multiple instance concept, that div contains header and content,, in the header I append 3 buttons and write code for those buttons.. then I have created 3 objects. when I click that button, then corresponding div only reacted that event, But actually what I'm getting is, whatever button is clicked, then 1st object only reacted, What should I do now?
Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var Window = function createwindow(title, word) {
            this.title = title;
            this.word = word;
            //div
           this.div = $('<div/>').attr({ 'id': 'div1' }).appendTo("body");
            $('body').css({
                "padding-top": "50px",
                "padding-right": "50px",
                "padding-bottom": "50px",
                "padding-left": "50px"
            });
            $(this.div).css({
                "height": "780px",
                "width": "780px",
                "border": "1px solid black",
                "display-align": "center",
                /*         "padding-top": "50px",
                           "padding-right": "50px",
                           "padding-bottom": "50px",
                           "padding-left": "50px"      */
            });

            //header
            this.header = $('<div/>').attr({ 'id': 'header' }).appendTo("#div1");
            $(this.header).text(this.title).css({
                "font-size": "40px",
                "text-align": "center",
                "text-transform": "uppercase",
                "color": "white",
                "text-shadow": " 2px 2px red"
            });

            $(this.header).css({
                "height": "100px",
                "border-bottom": "1px solid black",
                "width": "780px"
            });

            //content
            this.content = $('<div/>').attr({ 'id': 'content' }).appendTo("#div1");
            $(this.content).text(this.word).css({
                "margin-left": "auto",
                "margin-right": "auto",
                "width": "70%"
            });
            $(this.content).css({
                "height": "680px",
                //       "width":"780px",
                //  "border": "1px solid black",
                "text-align": "center",
                "font-size": "30px",
                "color": "green"
            });

            //images

            this.img1 = $('<img/>').attr({
                'id': 'mini',
                'src': 'mini.jpg',
                'height': '20px',
                'width': '20px',
                'position': 'static',
                'right': '0px'

            }).appendTo(this.header);


            this.img2 = $('<img/>').attr({
                'id': 'restore',
                'src': 'restore.jpg',
                'height': '20px',
                'width': '20px',
                'position': 'static',
                'right': '0px'

            }).appendTo(this.header);


            this.img3 = $('<img/>').attr({
                'id': 'close',
                'src': 'close1.jpg',
                'height': '20px',
                'width': '20px',
                'position': 'static',
                'right': '0px'
            }).appendTo(this.header);

            //event for images

            this.img1.bind('click', function () {
                    $('#content').slideToggle("slow");
                });


            this.img2.bind('click', function () {
                    $('#div1').css({
                        "height": "360px",
                        "width": "360px",
                    });
                    $('#header').css({
                        "height": "50px",
                        "width": "360px",
                    });
                    $('#content').css({
                        "height": "340px",
                    });
                });

            this.img2.bind('dblclick', function () {
                    $('#div1').css({
                        "height": "780px",
                        "width": "780px",
                    });
                    $('#header').css({
                        "height": "100px",
                        "width": "780px",
                    });
                    $('#content').css({
                        "height": "680px",
                    });

                });

            this.img3.bind('click', function (event) {
                    $('#div1,#header,#content').hide(this.div);
              });


        }
            var s = new Window("Homepage", "I'm first window");
            var p = new Window("FirstPage", "I'm second window");
            var k = new Window("SecondPage", "I'm Third window");



  });



    </script>
```

Comment: The parameter passed to `.hide()` is a duration over which to hide the selections (*or* an object of animation options). You've passed in a jQuery object.

Comment: if you don't mind can you explain a little bit more. If I don't give event to hide, only giving hide() for img3 means it will react on every object, what I make a mistake here  ...Thanks in advance@George

Comment: First thing's first, you need to ensure IDs are unique document-wide. Read about [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same ID's for all your elements (you have multiple #content, multiple #header, multiple #div1...) so the click can only be fired on the first element having this ID. An ID must be unique (#div1, #div2, ...). If you want to keep the same name for many elements you must use the `class` attribute, or use different ID's.

For example, by adding a new parameter number to your `createwindow` function:

```
var Window = function createwindow(title, word, number) {
    this.div = $('<div/>').attr({ 'id': 'div'+number }).appendTo("body");
    ...
}
var s = new Window("Homepage", "I'm first window", 1);
var p = new Window("FirstPage", "I'm second window", 2);
var k = new Window("SecondPage", "I'm Third window", 3);
```

You will have to change the rest of your code accordingly (use classes instead of ID's for header and content, update your click events so they target the parent #divX, etc.)

Comment: if you don't mind can you tell how to dynamically change the div id name? because I'm trying to assign the class name of the div and did the code means it generate undesired output...Thanks in advance @Guillaume

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to "dynamically" set the div IDs. You will still have to update the rest of your code accordingly.